# Problem with importing data to google colab

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

I have an error when I want to import my data to `colab` from my drive. If someone knows why I will be pleased to know.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
Webshop_train_2023 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Thierry /Titi /Webshop_train_2023.csv")
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7276aceb36b1> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Webshop_train_2023 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Thierry /Titi /Webshop_train_2023.csv")

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    676     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    677 
--> 678     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    573 
    574     # Create the parser.
--> 575     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    576 
    577     if chunksize or iterator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    930 
    931         self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 932         self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
    933 
    934     def close(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1232 
   1233         try:
-> 1234             return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1235         except Exception:
   1236             if self.handles is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     73 
     74         kwds["dtype"] = ensure_dtype_objs(kwds.get("dtype", None))
---> 75         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     76 
     77         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 2786: invalid continuation byte
```

No have tried so much

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the encoding, I assume your csv file have language other than English.

try

```
Webshop_train_2023 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Thierry /Titi /Webshop_train_2023.csv",
 engine = "python")
```

or

```
Webshop_train_2023 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Thierry /Titi /Webshop_train_2023.csv",
 encoding = "utf-8")
```

or if you know which encoder to use to decode the language change "utf-8" to that.